# Read static files using Karma

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner

Is is possible to read static JSON files in a Karma test? I would like to store the testdata in separate files.

I tried reading the files using require, but I didn't get that working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the requirejs's text plugin. It works perfectly well for this: https://github.com/requirejs/text